# how to integrate a html template in angular 7 project

Tags: angular, typescript, templates

I'm integrating a html template in angular 7 project and it is not working correctly

I added the template files under assets/template/.. and i added the imports in angular.json like:

- "styles":  ["src/assets/template/css/style-customizer.css",...],
- "scripts": ["src/assets/template/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js",...]

I edited the html code :

- removed doctype and html tags
- removed all the header
- removed all css and js imports
- edited the images sources

(like  src="/assets/template/img/slider/1.jpg" alt="main slider" title="#htmlcaption1")

I added the html code in index.html under the app-root tag and all working fine

But when i change it to app.component.html :

- some images not showing
- some css are not working correctly
- and some animations not working

and I don't have any error in my console

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnX4VxCLmbM) tutorial

Comment: in the video, he downloaded a pre-prepared angular project with an integrated theme, then he run 'npm install' to download libraries, that is not what i need.
i already have a project that im working on, and i want to integrate a html theme (not angular theme)

Comment: @HassenTayech. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't use styles array in angular.json, 
Instead, I import all global styles in styles .css as it is set into angular.json styles array by default.

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import "assets/quote.css";

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:200|Josefin+Sans:300|Julius+Sans+One|Merriweather+Sans:400|Overpass:400|Quicksand"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in `@component` like below mentioned.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```